# Why do we take the transpose after flattening an image

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, reshape, transpose

I am currently trying to learning deeplearning and numpy. In an example given, after reshaping a test set of 60 128x128 images of carrots by using

```
    `carrots_test.reshape(carrots_test.shape[60],-1)`
```

The example went on to then add a T to the end. I understand that this means a transpose but why would you transpose this new flattened image.

I understand what it is to flatten an image and why but can't intuitively see why we need to transpose (swap the rows and columns) it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global reason to do it. Your application expects the shape to be `(elements, images)`, not `(images, elements)`. A `reshape` only adjusts the shape of the buffer. `transpose` adjusts the strides of the dimensions and compensates by rearranging the shape.